# Is there any public implementation of dm-default-key module for android kernels?

Tags: android, kernel-module, device-mapper

Android 9.0 states that there is some support for metadata encryption (https://source.android.com/security/encryption/metadata).
This seems to require presence of some "dm-default-key" module.
It appears that I did not find any reference of this module on my kernel (4.9), nor on those I browsed on the internet.
Does anyone know where to find more information on how to implement it in the kernel? I have no specification on what it is expected to do, nor any reference implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

https://github.com/kdrag0n/proton_bluecross/blob/master/drivers/md/dm-default-key.c

Hit the history button to see history of this file

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is on the most recent kernel for Pixel 3 XL devices:

https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm/+/refs/heads/android-msm-crosshatch-4.9-q-preview-6/drivers/md/dm-default-key.c